# How can I alternate the column count per row?

Tags: php, object, foreach

I have a PHP object with around 90 items. I am trying to output these in rows with alternating columns. My current code is outputting 2 items per row is:

```
<?php 
    $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
    $_columnCount = 2;
    $i = 0;
?>

<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

    <?php if ($i++ % $_columnCount == 0): ?>
        <section class="row">
    <?php endif ?>

            <div class="six columns"></div>

    <?php if ($i % $_columnCount == 0 || $i == $_collectionSize): ?>
        </section>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I modify this code to alternate the column count for each row so that the output would be like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="six columns"></div>
    <div class="six columns"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns"></div> 
    <div class="three columns"></div>
    <div class="three columns"></div>
    <div class="three columns"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="six columns"></div>
    <div class="six columns"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns"></div> 
    <div class="three columns"></div>
    <div class="three columns"></div>
    <div class="three columns"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Google for PHP Template Engine (like Smarty or Twig). You can thank me later ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would chunk my array in chunks by two, and then hold next needed key for outputting different markup:

```
$items = array(
    'Product 1',
    'Product 2',
    'Product 3',
    'Product 4',
    'Product 5',
    'Product 6',
    'Product 7',
    'Product 8',
    'Product 9',
    'Product 10',
    'Product 11',
    'Product 12',    
);

$chunked = array_chunk($items, 2);

// variable to hold next <div class="six columns"></div> markup
$needle = 0;

foreach ($chunked as $key => $items) {

    if ($key == $needle) {
        if ($key !== 0) echo "</div>\n";
        echo "<div class=\"row\">\n";
        foreach($items as $item) {
            echo "<div class=\"six columns\">{$item}</div>\n";
        }
        echo "</div>\n<div class=\"row\">\n";
        // skip two array items
        $needle = $needle + 3;
    } else {
        foreach($items as $item) {
            echo "<div class=\"three columns\">{$item}</div>\n";
        }
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

[Working demo](http://www.tehplayground.com/#1POvlzSZg)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that, using a modulo of 2 ? :

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

    <?php if ($i++ % $_columnCount == 0): ?>
        <section class="row">
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($i % 2 == 0): ?>
            <div class="six columns"></div>
            <div class="six columns"></div>
    <?php else ?>
            <div class="three columns"></div> 
            <div class="three columns"></div>
            <div class="three columns"></div>
            <div class="three columns"></div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($i % $_columnCount == 0 || $i == $_collectionSize): ?>
        </section>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this isn't what I want. This outputs 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6. per row. I need a row of 6, 6, then 3, 3, 3, 3 alternating